# Missing project level settings

Tags: intellij-idea

I am running 2018.3 CE of IntelliJ on MacOS Mojave. For some reason I when I pick Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle I don't see any of the "Project-level settings". Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a project open that was imported from `build.gradle`? Some options become available only with the open project and not from the Welcome Screen. Some options are also hidden if the project was not imported from Gradle.

Comment: The project was imported from existing source and not from build.gradle. However the source is built by gradle with a build.gradle file. Is there any way that the "Project Settings" can be enabled now.

Comment: No, you need to import the project from `build.gradle`.